# Клиент-серверная программа: слушать каждый порт в отдельном потоке

Tags: c, g++, gcc, c++, linux

Я пишу клиент серверную программу и необходимо, чтобы каждый порт слушался в отдельном потоке. Когда два потока на порты (основной и один побочный) все нормально работает, но при попытке увеличить число портов перестает работать и выдает ошибку `bind: Address already in use.`
Уже долго бьюсь с этим. Ниже отправил коды сервера и клиента:

server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
#define n 8
#define privkey 37
#define publickey 11413
#define count_key 18643
#define NEW_USER 1
#define GET_PORT 0
#define CONFIRM_SMS 2
#define AUTHORIZ 3

using namespace std;

int port_connect[n];
int port_connect_count[n];
void *connect_port(void *arg);
void *extrim_connect(void *arg);
int confirm(int sock);
int autho(int sock);
int new_user(int sock);

int min_port()//минимальный порт
{
    int min=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(port_connect_count[min]>port_connect_count[i])
       { min=i;
       printf("\nmin=%d\n",i);
    }
    return port_connect[min];
}

int start()//запускает основаной порт и экстренный порт
    {
        pthread_t thread[n];
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)//запускаем порты
        {
          pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, connect_port, &i);
        }
       pthread_create(&thread[n-1], NULL, extrim_connect, &i);//запускаем экстренный порт
     //   i--;
     //   pthread_create(&thread[n], NULL, extrim_connect, &i);
    int sock;
    int listener;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listener < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    fcntl(listener, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    int port=3264;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(2);
    }

    listen(listener, 2);

    set<int> clients;
    clients.clear();

    while(1)
    {
        // Заполняем множество сокетов
        fd_set readset;
        FD_ZERO(&readset);
        FD_SET(listener, &readset);

        for(set<int>::iterator it = clients.begin(); it != clients.end(); it++)
            FD_SET(*it, &readset);

        // Задаём таймаут
        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 15;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        // Ждём события в одном из сокетов
        int mx = max(listener, *max_element(clients.begin(), clients.end()));
        if(select(mx+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout) <= 0)
        {
           // perror("select");
            continue;
            //exit(3);
        }

        // Определяем тип события и выполняем соответствующие действия
        if(FD_ISSET(listener, &readset))
        {
            // Поступил новый запрос на соединение, используем accept
            int sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
            if(sock < 0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(3);
            }
            fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

            clients.insert(sock);
        }

        for(set<int>::iterator it = clients.begin(); it != clients.end(); it++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(*it, &readset))
            {
                // Поступили данные от клиента, читаем их
                bytes_read = recv(*it, buf, 1024, 0);
                /*
                 * рассшифровать buf
                 */
                if(bytes_read <= 0)
                {
                    // Соединение разорвано, удаляем сокет из множества
                    close(*it);
                    clients.erase(*it);
                    continue;
                }
                int k=atoi(buf);
                printf("\nk=%d\n",k);
                if(k==0)
                {   char mes[1024];
                    sprintf(mes, "%d", min_port());
                    printf("\n%s\n%d\n",mes,min_port());
                    send(*it, mes, 1024, 0); 
                }
                else 
                {
                     char *me=new char[100];
                     me=strcpy(me,"");
                     sprintf(me,"%d",-1);
                     printf("\nme=%s\n",me);
                     send(*it, me,1024, 0);
                }
                //здесь будут действия сервера в ответ на запрос клиента
                // Отправляем данные обратно клиенту

            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * 
 */
void *extrim_connect(void *arg)//экстренный порт
      {
    int listener;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read; 
    int sock;

    int count_port=* (int *)arg;
    int port=port_connect[count_port];
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listener < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        close( listener );
        exit(2);
    }

    listen(listener, 1);

    while(1)
    {
        sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(3);
        }

        switch(fork())
        {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            break;

        case 0:
            close(listener);
            int er;
            while(1)
            {

                bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
                if(bytes_read <= 0) break; 
                int k=atoi(buf);
                if(k==0)
                {
                char *me=new char[100];
                me=strcpy(me,"");
                sprintf(me,"%d",min_port());
                send(sock, me, sizeof(me), 0);
                } else
                {
                    char *me=new char[100];
                    me=strcpy(me,"");
                    sprintf(me,"%d",-1);
                    send(sock, me, sizeof(me), 0);
                }

            }

            close(sock);
            _exit(0);

        default:
            close(sock);
        }
    }

    close(listener);
  }

void *connect_port(void *arg)//порты работа с которыми осуществляется
  {
    int listener;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read; 
    int sock;

    int count_port=* (int *)arg;
    int port=port_connect[count_port];
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listener < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        close( listener );
        exit(2);
    }

    listen(listener, 1);

    while(1)
    {
        sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(3);
        }

        switch(fork())
        {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            break;

        case 0:
            close(listener);
         //   int er=12;
            while(1)
            {

                bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
                if(bytes_read <= 0) break; 
                int k=atoi(buf);
              /*  switch(k)
                {
                    case NEW_USER:
                        er=new_user(sock);
                        break;
                    case CONFIRM_SMS:  
                       er=confirm(sock);
                       if(er==0)
                       er=autho( sock);
                        break; 
                    case AUTHORIZ: 
                        er=autho( sock);
                        break;
                    default: break;           
                }*/
                char *me=new char[100];
                me=strcpy(me,"111");
              //  sprintf(me,"%d",er);
                send(sock, me, sizeof(me), 0);
            }

            close(sock);
            _exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            close(sock);
        }
    }

    close(listener);
  }

int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        port_connect[i]=7500+i;
    }
   // printf("%d",port_connect[n-1]);
    start();
    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char* message=new char[100];
char buf[sizeof(message)];

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3552); // или любой другой порт...
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }
    int k;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"\nVvedi soobsh"<<endl;
        cin>>k;
        message=strcpy(message,"");
        sprintf(message,"%d",k);
        send(sock, message, 1024, 0);
        recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
        cout<<buf<<endl;
        if(k==-1)
        break;
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Мне необходимо чтобы порты запустились, а дальше я разберусь.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот в этом коде ошибка.

```
for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)//запускаем порты
        {
          pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, connect_port, &i);
        }
       pthread_create(&thread[n-1], NULL, extrim_connect, &i);//запускаем экстренный порт
```

Дело в том, что Вы передаете в функцию потока **адрес одной и той же переменной i**. 
А ее значение меняется в главном потоке. В момент, когда потоки запустятся (в одних это будет функция connect_port(), а в другом extrim_connect()) значение **i** будет скорее всего n - 1 во всех потоках. Т.е. одинаковым для всех потоках (параметр arg в обеих функциях это адрес одной и той же **i**.

*Вот bind() и ругается.*

Будьте проще, передавайте не адрес, а значение. Напишите:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, connect_port, (void *)(long)i);
....
pthread_create(&thread[n-1], NULL, extrim_connect, (void *)(long)i);//запускаем экстренный порт
```

**i** надо преобразовывать в long, чтобы на 64-бит компе компилятор не ругался, что размер адреса и переменной i (а она у Вас типа int) разный.

Comment: @avp: и не лень вам было искать ошибку в такой простыне!

+1.

Comment: @avp в общем случае sizeof(long) != sizeof(void *).

Comment: @Dith, в общем случае, наверное Вы правы. В Linux абсолютно точно, что размеры long и указателя равны и равны размеру РОН.

Для остальных \*nix IMHO это тоже так.

--

@VladD, а я всю простыню даже не смотрел. Нашел bind, нашел вызовы функций с bind и увидел типичную ошибку вызова потока.